# Why does vs code debug console break python print statements?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

After a vscode upgrade (to v1.33.0), Python's print function adds extra spacing on debug console. Print function breaks for no good reason. Extra space is added filling up screen with blanks. Any ideas to get python print statements back on track?

Issue was closed in 2017 https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17526# but is back on.

a='1'
b='2'
print (a,b)

Expected: 1 2
Got: 1

2